# How to work with varargs and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

Simple question, how make this code working ?

```
public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new T().m();
    }

    public // as mentioned by Bozho
    void foo(String... s) {
        System.err.println(s[0]);
    }

    void m() throws Exception {
        String[] a = new String[]{"hello", "kitty"};
        System.err.println(a.getClass());
        Method m = getClass().getMethod("foo", a.getClass());
        m.invoke(this, (Object[]) a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", String[].class);
```

works. The problem is that `getMethod(..)` only searches the `public` methods. From the javadoc:

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

**Update:** After successfully getting the method, you can invoke it using:

```
m.invoke(this, new Object[] {new String[] {"a", "s", "d"}});
```

that is - create a new `Object` array with one element - the `String` array. With your variable names it would look like:

```
m.invoke(this, new Object[] {a});
```

Comment: Thanks! But now i get stucked at the invocation.

Comment: @PeterMmm good. btw, it is an accepted practice to upvote useful (inc. the accepted) answers. You have only 2 upvotes, which is contrary to the idea of SO.

Comment: You can also do `m.invoke(this, (Object) a);` (see my solution).

Comment: @Bozho, my case is: void foo() function has argument Param... param (Hint: Param is generic type) instead of String... s. I used        new Object[] {new URL("http://google.com")}, but get the following error:  IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type java.lang.Object[], got java.net.URL

Answer (score 13):

//prior to edit:

Your problem is the fact that `getMethod` looks for a `public` member.

From the [`Class.getMethod`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a `Method` object that reflects the specified **public** member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object

So you have two options:

- Make `public void foo(String... s)` and use `getMethod`
- Use `getDeclaredMethod` instead

Note that the same difference exists for `getField/s` vs `getDeclaredField/s` and `getConstructor/s` vs `getDeclaredConstructor/s`.

---

//`invoke` problem

This is particularly nasty, but what happens is that `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` makes it tricky if you need to pass an array of reference type as an only argument, because it is cast-able to `Object[]`, even though it should be wrapped inside a `new Object[1]` instead.

You can do:

```
m.invoke(this, new Object[] {a}); // Bohzo's solution
```

This bypasses the vararg mechanism. More succinctly you can also do:

```
m.invoke(this, (Object) a);
```

The cast to `Object` makes the vararg mechanism do the work of creating the array for you.

The trick is also needed when passing a `null` as an argument to varargs, and has nothing to do with reflection.

```
public void foo(String... ss) {
    System.out.println(ss[0]);
}

    foo(null); // causes NullPointerException
    foo((String) null); // prints "null"
```

Comment: @polygenelubricants, my case is: void foo() function has argument Param... param (Hint: Param is generic type) instead of String... s. I used new Object[] {new URL("google.com")}, but get the following error: IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type java.lang.Object[], got java.net.URL. Thank you in advance.