# What class parameter type should should be passed for variable arg Object array

Tags: java

If I have to pass an Object... var arguments parameter as input to the [Method.invoke](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) call, what should I specify as the parameter type for the [Class.getMethod](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class.getMethod("methodName", Object[].class)
```

**UPDATE**
[How to work with varargs and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection) provides more precise answer by Bozho

Comment: I think you misread the question -- Method.invoke takes Object ... regardless of the formal parameters of the declared method.

Comment: Actually @Vance - I think @denis got it right.  Either way, only the OP really knows for sure what he means.

Answer (score 0):

You're best off if you can specify the Classes that represent the real formal parameters of the method, as in its declaration. If you can't, the rules for resolution (at the link you provide) are not the most transparent.