# What type is Params in Android's AsyncTask->execute(Params...)

Tags: java, reflection

I am using java reflection to call a method "execute" on a runtime-determined class object, which extends AsyncTask

```
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[] {Class.forName("java.lang.Object")};           
// ObjAT is the runtime-determined AsyncTask object. 
Method method = objAT.getClass().getMethod("execute", parameterTypes);
```

`Class.forName("java.lang.Object")` is not the correct type of Param. Can anyone tell me what type of Param is, i.e. what should I use in Class.forName("") instead of "java.lang.Object"

Because I'm calling AsyncTask->execute(Param...);

Comment: `Param` is a generic type

Comment: Thx boxed__, but what exactly should I put in Class.forName("");?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection), you should try code like this:

```
// ObjAT is the runtime-determined AsyncTask object.
Method method = objAT.getClass().getMethod("execute", Object[].class);
```

Comment: Sorry, Params's class type is not String[].class. Thank you for your answer tho.