# Dynamic object creation in java using reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, constructor

What does `Class[] null` and `Object[] null` mean in the code below?

```
public Object selfFactory() {
    Class cl = this.getClass();
    Constructor cons;
    cons = cl.getConstructor((Class[]) null);
    return cons.newInstance((Object[]) null);
}
```

Comment: First statement casts it to type `Class` and second statement casts null to type `Object` - You can cast null to any reference type without getting any exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cl.getConstructor((Class[]) null);` takes the parameter for both its value and type as a type parameter `<T>`, so casting is necessary if we're supplying a `null` `Class[]` instead of a `null` `Object` for method invocation of `.getConstructor()`.

Similarly, `cons.newInstance((Object[]) null);` creates a new instance of `cl` by invoking a constructor `cons` which takes an `Object[]`, given as `null` in this case. Without the typecast, a null `Object` will be passed.

This is useful for when methods or constructors are overloaded. Invocation with `null` without cast will be of type `Object` and often ambiguous:

```
{
    eat(null); // ???
}

void eat(int[] arr);
void eat(Class arr);
```

With a cast, the correct constructor or method can be called.

```
{
    eat((Class) null);
}
```

Also as documented by [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) in [How to work with varargs and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600945/3622940),

> *[...]* `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` makes it tricky if you need to pass an array of reference type as an only argument, because it is cast-able to `Object[]`, even though it should be wrapped inside a `new Object[1]` instead.
>
> You can do:
>
> ```
> m.invoke(this, new Object[] {a}); // Bohzo's solution
> ```
>
> This bypasses the vararg mechanism. More succinctly you can also do:
>
> ```
> m.invoke(this, (Object) a);
> ```
>
> The cast to `Object` makes the vararg mechanism do the work of creating the array for you.
>
> The trick is also needed when passing a `null` as an argument to varargs, and has nothing to do with reflection.
>
> ```
> public void foo(String... ss) {
>     System.out.println(ss[0]);
> }
>
>     foo(null); // causes NullPointerException
>     foo((String) null); // prints "null"
> ```

Comment: so if i have myType(), myType(int x) and myType(Object x) as constructors in myType class, how can i modify the code to call the 2nd one with the int parameter?

Comment: @Unihedron 0 is not really a valid Class :( Instead `cl.getConstructor(Integer.class)` should do the trick. alternatively `cl.getDeclaredConstructors()[1]`

Comment: Thanks Vog I was looking at the wrong thing. @mike_x_ ^

Comment: and what should i pass as a param in newinstance() if i have one int parameter?

Comment: @mike An `int` value equal to what you're calling it with.