# IllegalArgumentException when combining varargs and string arrays in EL

Tags: java, arrays, jsf, el, variadic-functions

I am getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` when trying to pass a string array to a method with varargs via EL.
I know that EL does not support arrays or varargs. So I wanted to pass the parameter in use of a attribute in a CDI bean.

The only problem seems to be (or related to) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection). Is this simply not supported in EL or am I missing something?

Here is my setting:

Class with String array parameter:

```
@Named
public class Test
{
    private String[] test = new String[]{"a", "b"};

    public String[] getTest()
    {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String[] test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Class with method expecting varargs:

```
@Named
public class Method
{
    public void method(String ... args)
    {
    }
}
```

Use in facelet:

```
<p:commandButton
    rendered="#{method.method(test.test)}" />
```