# Reflection: get the method with arbitrary number of arguments and use it as such

Tags: java, reflection

I want to use a method from a 3rd party package I use. This is the signature:

`java.lang.String buildMenuPath(java.lang.Object... objects);`

The method can be used as follows (to name a few):

1. `buildMenuPath(1,1,1) //3 ints`
2. `buildMenuPath("str",1,1) // 1 string 2 ints`
3. `buildMenuPath("str",1) // 1 string 1 int`

Through reflection, I try to get this method and follow usage #2 and #3.

Attempt #1, getting the exact signature I will use (`String.class, Integer.class`)

```
ArrayList pathArr = new ArrayList();
pathArr.add("Window");
pathArr.add(i);
Method method  = myObj.getClass().getMethod("buildMenuPath",String.class, Integer.class);
method.invoke(myObj,pathArr.toArray())
```

- Throws: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`

Attempt #2, getting the arbitrary arguments method:

```
ArrayList pathArr = new ArrayList();
pathArr.add("Window");
pathArr.add(i);
Method method  = myObj.getClass().getMethod("buildMenuPath",Object[].class);
method.invoke(myObj,pathArr.toArray())
```

- Looks like it gets the method but throws: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

But if I call manually, with `myObj.buildMenuPath("Window",6);` it works.

How can I solve this problem through reflection?

Comment: Varargs is syntactic sugar done by the compiler. As far as the JVM, and hence reflection, is concerned, the signature of the method is `buildMenuPath(Object[] objects)`, so that's the method you should look for.

Comment: Try `method.invoke(myObj, new Object[] {new Object[] {"Window", i}})` in Attempt #2.  And see [How to work with varargs and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection).

Comment: @saka1029 thanks - the problem is I construct `pathArr` dynamically, so I won't *(easily)* know at the time I call `.invoke` how many args I want to call with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the exact signature of the function (look through documentation), it may take a variable list of arguments of Object type for example, or it may be overloaded, but the argument types may not be `String` and `int`.

Finally, when calling `Invoke()`, cast the array of arguments to `(Object)`

In your case, should be:

```
ArrayList pathArr = new ArrayList();
pathArr.add("Window");
pathArr.add(i);
Method method  = myObj.getClass().getMethod("buildMenuPath",Object[].class);
method.invoke(myObj,(Object)pathArr.toArray())
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? What do you think the following is? *This is the signature: `java.lang.String buildMenuPath(java.lang.Object... objects);`*

Comment: sorry, I missed that. You should cast your array to (Object) when calling Invoke()

Comment: @oviuan thank you.  casting solved the problem, just as the answer in the duplicate link said. If you edit your answer to clarify that I'll upvote & accept it. thanks

Comment: Thanks @Adelin, added the edit. Sorry again about missing the signature line :)